# Spring Security having two authentication layers

Tags: spring, spring-security

In our application, we are required to have two layers of authentication,Database and LDAP, i.e,

Once User logins with username and password, Database validation is done only to check if username exists in database using custom authentication privider.

If username exists in the database then second layer of LDAP has to be invoked to check if password matches.If password matches with that in LDAP then user should be authenticated.If username doesn't exist in the database, the LDAP layer shouldn't be invoked and user shouldn't be authenticated.

I have implemented the first layer of authentication i.e Database validation for username.
    However I am not able to figure out how I can have second layer i.e LDAP for password check.
    It would be great if someone helps me on this.

Below is the code in security xml file:

```
    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true"

              entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

              <security:custom-filter ref="customAuthenticationFilter"

                     position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />

              <security:custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" />

              <security:access-denied-handler

                     error-page="/accessDenied" />

              <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/logout" />

              <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />



           <security:headers >

               <security:cache-control />

               <security:hsts/>

           </security:headers>

       </security:http>

       <security:global-method-security

              pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

       <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

              <security:authentication-provider

                     ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />

       </security:authentication-manager>

       <bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"

              class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

              <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/">

              </property>

       </bean>



       <bean id="customAuthenticationFilter"

              class="com.honeywell.wfm.util.CustomAuthenticationFilter">

              <property name="usernameParameter" value="username"></property>

              <property name="passwordParameter" value="password"></property>

              <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>

              <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>

              <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>

              <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />

       </bean>





       <bean id="successHandler"

              class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">

              <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/dashboard"/>

       </bean>

       <bean id="failureHandler"

              class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">

              <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/failTologin"/>

       </bean>



       <bean id="concurrencyFilter"

        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">

        <property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />

        <property name="expiredUrl" value="/logout" />

    </bean>


    <bean id="sas"

        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy">

        <constructor-arg>

            <list>

                <bean

                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">

                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />

                    <property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />

                    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="false" />

                </bean>

                <bean

                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy">

                </bean>

                <bean

                    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">

                    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry" />

                </bean>

            </list>

        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionRegistry"

        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />





       <bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">

              <property name="rolePrefix" value="" />

       </bean>

       <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider"

              class="com.honeywell.wfm.service.impl.CustomAuthenticationProvider"></bean>







CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {



              String employeeNumber = authentication.getName();

              String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

              UserDTO userDTO = loginComponent.loadUserByUsername(employeeNumber);

              if (userDTO.getEmployeeNo() == null) {

                     logger.error("Authentication failure for "+employeeNumber);

                     throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Employee Number");

              }

              logger.info("Successfully Authenticated " +userDTO.getUserName());

              userDTO.setPassword(password);

              return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDTO, password, userDTO.getAuthorities());

}
```

Comment: You can create three Spring-managed beans - first that checks the availability of the username in the RDBMS, second that validates the password with LDAP and the third an `AuthenticationProvider` that orchestrates the first and second beans.

Comment: Could you please explain how to validate password against LDAP with Java code

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Validation simply means comparison. First find out how passwords are stored in your LDAP store (plain, encrypted, hashed, etc.) and then perform the appropriate comparison. If you have a specific question, post it along with the code you have tried.